# How to solve following problem in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, arrays, string, search, methods

We have an array that holds many web site names. Eg, [www.google.com](http://www.google.com), [www.msn.com](http://www.msn.com), [www.amazon.co.in](http://www.amazon.co.in), in.answers.yahoo.com, en.m.wikipedia.com, codehs.gitbooks.io,www.coderanch.com etc. Search for all sites that begin with “www” and display the total number of such sites. Eg. for the above, the total is 4.

I have tried using `string.search()` and `string.match()` methods and also used `Regular Expressions` but none of them worked. Can anyone help me out?
I tried:

```
function myFun(){
                var arr = ["www.google.com", "www.msn.com", "www.amazon.co.in", "in.answers.yahoo.com", 
                            "en.m.wikipedia.com", "codehs.gitbooks.io", "www.coderanch.com"];
                
                var count = 0;
                var str= arr.toString();
                console.log(str);
                if(str == /www/g){
                    count ++;
                }
                document.write(count);
            }
```

Comment: Show what you tried that did not work....

Comment: Why not use `str.startsWith('www')`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```js
function myFun(){
    let arr = [
      "www.google.com",
      "www.msn.com",
      "www.amazon.co.in",
      "in.answers.yahoo.com", 
      "en.m.wikipedia.com",
      "codehs.gitbooks.io",
      "www.coderanch.com"
    ];
    let count = arr.reduce((c,i)=> {
      i.split(".")[0]==='www' && c++ ;
      return c;
    },0);
    document.write(count);
}

myFun();
```

Answer (score 0):

```javascript
function searchWebsite(){
    var arr = ["www.google.com", "www.msn.com", "www.amazon.co.in", "in.answers.yahoo.com", "en.m.wikipedia.com", "codehs.gitbooks.io", "www.coderanch.com"];
    var count = 0;
    var pattern = new RegExp("www", "i");
    for(i=0;i<arr.length;i++){
        var result = pattern.test(arr[i]);
        if(result){
        count ++;
         }
    }
    document.write(count);
}
```

Comment: Can you [edit] your answer to explain your code, what you edit and why ?